# Typedoc: document only things exported by a specific file

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typedoc

I am developing two npn packages:

- https://github.com/euberdeveloper/mongo-scanner
- https://github.com/euberdeveloper/mongo-cleaner

I want to document them by using typedoc. The index.js file is the one provided by the npm module and is obtained by index.ts.

I want to document only what is exported by the library index.ts. I can filter the non-exported things with the typedoc options.

The problem is that the index.ts import things from other TS files and export only some of them. For instance, it imports and re-exports some interfaces from the interfaces/index.ts and the errors classes from errors/index.ts, but imports without exporting the class Database from the utils/database/index.ts.

Being actually exported, things such that Database class are documented even if they are exported by a file different from index.ts.

How can I filter them?

Comment: In v0.17 (currently a beta release under `typedoc@next`) this will be possible with `--mode library`

Comment: Thank you, I noticed it in the project section of the github repo. When will this become part of the stable release?

Comment: I'm hoping to release it this month, back in school now though so I don't have much time to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current @next version of typedoc has a --library mode. Seems that there are going to be big changes with the @beta version and the future 1.0.0 version, where the mode option will even disappear. Development seems to proceed extremely slow, so I think that the only way now is to use the (probably bugged) @next and @beta versions and wait.

**Edit: the 0.20.x is no more beta and has been released, it works good, so the problem is solved**

Comment: I guess I deserved extremely slow... it's out now though!

Comment: Sorry, I had some libraries that waited for a stable library mode. Now I tried it and it works, I thing there has been a good improvement. Is there a way to still use the older way ("modules" mode), in order to have a version for who will use the library and another version for who develops it?

Comment: "modules" mode is really library mode with the entry point being every single file in the project